# Sql Server: Updating 70 million records. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this script?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table of medical claims named "Claim_Lookup" and a field in the table called CompanyID.  I need to update all existing records with a companyID of 1, so I setup a script to do so in batches of 2000 at a time.  In our dev  environment, after 2hrs 30 min, so far it's completed 8 million of the 70 million total.  Is there any way to improve the performance of this query or should I perhaps add an index or something to this field?

Here's the field in my table.  No indexes are setup:

```
[CompanyID] [int] NULL
```

And here's my script to run in batches of 2000 at a time:

```
DECLARE @Rows INT,
    @BatchSize INT; -- keep below 5000 to be safe

SET @BatchSize = 2000;

SET @Rows = @BatchSize; -- initialize just to enter the loop

BEGIN TRY

  WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
  BEGIN
      UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) cl
      SET    cl.CompanyID = 1
      FROM  ClaimLoads.dbo.Claim_Lookup cl
      WHERE cl.CompanyID IS NULL

      SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
  END;

END TRY
begin catch
    -- Raise error
    declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000),
        @ErrorSeverity int,
        @ErrorState int
    select  @ErrorMessage = error_message(),
        @ErrorSeverity = error_severity(),
        @ErrorState = error_state()
    raiserror(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
end catch;
```

Comment: yes make an index on companyid and it will run much faster

Comment: Given that this is foreign key,, someone should have a good explanation if it does NOT have an index on it.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on this table? Is there a primary key on the table (so it's not a heap)?

Comment: Another suggestion if there is an index on the CompanyID which is being updated is to create a lookup table based on primary key, remove the index, join in the update statement, and then re create the index. This is so that the index is not being updated as a part of the query which can slow down the statement.

Comment: There is not a lot we can to outside recommending hardware because the OP prefers to provide ZERO relevant information.

Comment: `field`? They're called columns in a database table.

Comment: We need to see the execution plan in order to assist. Please google "sql paste the plan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get proper hardware. Last time did that - pretty much exactly this approach, looping and update top - I was doing that on a table with around 2 billion rows, it was a delete, not an update (so heavier) and I did batches of 64 million rows that deleted in around half a minute. And yes, that where loops of 64 million rows EACH TIME.

There is not a lot you can do with updates, and a lot runs down to hardware at some point. Start normal analysis (index on clCompanyID to start with - how long does it take to search for this?) and then look where your bottleneck is. if your dev environment is as most I have seen, the IO side AND the memory is so pathetic it makes your smartphone look like a super computer - and in this scenario any bulk operation takes ages.

More we can not say you kindly and amazingly provide ZERO information for analysis.